# How to Migrate Multiple tables in one shot from AWS DynamoDB to AWS DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

I'm new to AWS Glue & I wanted to migrate data from AWS one account to AWS other account for DynamoDB.

i Tried for single table & able migrate.

Here is the code!.

```
import boto3
import sys
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
glue_context = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
job = Job(glue_context)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

dyf = glue_context.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    connection_type="dynamodb",
    connection_options={
        "dynamodb.region": region,
        "dynamodb.splits": str(ddb_split),
        "dynamodb.throughput.read.percent": "1.2",
        "dynamodb.input.tableName": source_ddb_name
    }
)

glue_context.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    frame=dyf,
    connection_type="dynamodb",
    connection_options={
        "dynamodb.region": region,
        "dynamodb.output.tableName": target_ddb_name,
        "dynamodb.awsAccessKeyId": ddb_key,
        "dynamodb.awsSecretAccessKey": ddb_secret,
        "dynamodb.awsSessionToken": ddb_token
    }
)

print("dynamic frame got pushed to target!!!")
job.commit()
```

Now, I want to alter for multiple tables ?

Can any one help!

Thank You!

**I tried**

```
sc = SparkContext()
glue_context = GlueContext(sc)
broadcast_glue_context = sc.broadcast(glue_context)

broadcast_glue_context_write_dynamic_frame_from_options = sc.broadcast(glue_context.write_dynamic_frame_from_options)
broadcast_glue_context_create_dynamic_frame_from_options = sc.broadcast(glue_context.create_dynamic_frame_from_options)
sc.parallelize(["table1", "table2"]).flatMap(
    lambda table_name: (table_name, broadcast_glue_context_create_dynamic_frame_from_options.value()
               )
).foreach(lambda x: broadcast_glue_context_write_dynamic_frame_from_options.value(frame=x[1]))
```

Error :

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize broadcast: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

Comment: Check this out - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamodb-cross-account-migration/

Comment: You don't need Spark for the task. Check out @vivekveeramani link which suggests to dump DynamoDB data to S3 and then do a bulk load to the target DynamoDB

Comment: Thanks for reply vivekveeramani & @Emer. I don't want use S3 here.